# Printing "Wrong Type" when calling a function with the wrong input type - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make an error message appear when the wrong type of data is entered into a function. In this instance, I am only trying to accept an `int` or `float` when the function is called. Entering a `str` in the function should return an error message

```
def isPrime(i):

    if not (type(i)==float or type(i)==int):
        print("Input wrong type")
        return None

    i = abs(int(i))

    if i == 2 or i == 1: 
        return True    

    if not i & 1: 
        return False

    for x in range(3, int(i**0.5) + 1, 2):
        if i % x == 0:
            return False

    return True

# Wanting the code to return an error
isPrime(bob)
```

Comment: What is the question? How is your function mis-behaving?

Comment: `bob` is not a string … it is nothing since you haven't initialized it.  Try `isPrime('bob')`.

Comment: You shouldn't use `type() == typename`; in general you should use `isinstance(input, type)` instead. To give an error, you want to `raise` the error. In this case, since it's the wrong type, you can `raise TypeError` instead of `return None`. You can also raise an error with a specific error message like so: `raise TypeError('Input must be a float or int')`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code.  What are you setting `bob` to? What output do you get when you run your code?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python 3.5+, you can use type hint with the following decorator (which I adapted from @MartijnPieters's [typeconversion decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50079753/6890912)) to enforce the type hints:

```
import functools
import inspect

def enforce_types(f):
    sig = inspect.signature(f)
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        bound = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        bound.apply_defaults()
        args = bound.arguments
        for param in sig.parameters.values():
            if param.annotation is not param.empty and not isinstance(args[param.name], param.annotation):
                raise TypeError("Parameter '%s' must be an instance of %s" % (param.name, param.annotation))
        result = f(*bound.args, **bound.kwargs)
        if sig.return_annotation is not sig.empty and not isinstance(result, sig.return_annotation):
            raise TypeError("Returning value of function '%s' must be an instance of %s" % (f.__name__, sig.return_annotation))
        return result
    return wrapper

@enforce_types
def isPrime(i: float) -> bool:
    i = abs(int(i))
    if i == 2 or i == 1: 
        return True    
    if not i & 1: 
        return False
    for x in range(3, int(i**0.5) + 1, 2):
        if i % x == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

so that:

```
print(isPrime(1))
print(isPrime(1.0))
```

would both output `True`, but:

```
print(isPrime('one'))
```

would raise the following exception:

```
TypeError: Parameter 'i' must be an instance of <class 'float'>
```

Comment: Cool decorator! I think it should be part of standard library.

Answer (score 0):

So:

```
if not (type(i)==float or type(i)==int):
    print("Input wrong type")
    return None
```

Could be simplified to:

```
if not isinstance(i,(float,int)):
    print("Input wrong type")
    return None
```

Then do error message:

```
if not isinstance(i,(float,int)):
    raise TypeError('Your Text here') #You can do any error i do `TypeError` just for now.
```

Then to create own Error message:

```
class MyError(Exception):
    pass
```

Then here:

```
if not isinstance(i,(float,int)):
    raise MyError('Your Text here')
```

But I'll prefer to use `TypeError`, for doing errror

Comment: No need for the `return` after `raise`ing, but otherwise, short and to the point!

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Oh yeah that's correct, thanks a lot

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Done!

Comment: Keep TypeError. That's what it's for. No need to proliferate custom error types. Also, if you raise, don't bother printing. Just make the print message your error message.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah, that's right, edited, but just for OP to know how to create error message